# Access the internal memory of android through in independent java code

Tags: java, android, windows

I have created an xml file here: `/data/data/com.appName/emergency.xml`
Now I want to access this file from my desktop.

I am able to access the SD card through my java code. In this case, I think, the file is created in the internal memory of the device. So is it possible to access the file emergency.xml?

Comment: Now I want to access this file from my desktop. means?

Comment: no you can not because data needs root permission to be accessed

Comment: I mean, I want to copy the file from my android device to the PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a non-rooted device then you can't get that file from your desktop since it is readable only for the "com.appName" app. You can try to do "`adb pull /data/data/com.appName/emergency.xml`", but that should not work on a normal device.

But if "com.appName" is your app then you can let the app copy the file to a place where you can access it from your desktop (e.g. `/sdcard`).

Example Code for file copy: http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/CopyFile.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Now I know that this works on rooted devices (which you really should probably have if you want to do serious dev work), and I *THINK* it will work for nonroot devices. Basically you enter the adb shell and then do something like "dd if=/data/data/com.appName/emergency.xml of=/sdcard/emergency.xml". Then you should be able to pull the file with adb pull off the sdcard.